# Unique grid/flex layout for 8 items

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to solve a specific layout issue with grid/flex and cannot seem to find a proper answer. I have 8 items that I want to run in a 3 3 2 layout. Grid makes it easy but I want the two items in the last row to be centered vs left aligned.

The attached image is what I am trying to achieve.
[3 column, 8 item grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCLsb.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 6 column grid, not 3, then place your items accordingly.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:50px;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap:1em;
}

.box:nth-child(7) {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}

.box:nth-child(8) {
  grid-column: 4 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Flexbox requires setting a width of c.1/3 on the items.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like grid is the way to go. This is exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you!